# Is reusing the layout and adapter for recyclerview a good practice in Android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have 2 Activities- MainActivity and SecondActivity. Both activity contains recyclerview with same layout. So, i can easily use the same adapter and xml layouts for the recyclerviews.

But is it a good practice? My confusion is that - if both activities are live and using same xml resource isnt there going to be a problem? plus they are going to use same adapter.

Is this a good practice or bad ?

Comment: Always try to reuse code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple activities can use the same XML layout without problems, as they don't share actually inflated views. (Every activity inflates its own layout from given XML.)

I would recomend not to share the same adapter INSTANCE between activities - better make separate adapter-instance for each activity. (You can reuse adapter-class in multiple activities, if you need to do so.)